# How to se if input value with multiple words contains value from array in jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to check if a string like "me and her" contains a value from an array.
The array could look like:

[" and ", "Mr", "sir"]

If it does it should return false. That means that "John Doe" should return true but "Mr. John Doe" or "john and Jane Doe" should return false

I don't think I can use $.inArray as it only checks for the specific value and not part of the string.

Anyone?

Comment: why should Mr. John Doe return false? None of the words are exact matches of those in the array

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native JavaScript [String.includes()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) method to check if a string includes a value, then loop through your list of things.  Something like this:

```
function checkStringAgainstList(str) {
    var exclude = ['Mr', 'and', 'Mrs'];
    for (var ndx in exclude) {
        if(str.includes(exclude[ndx])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This seems like what you want.  Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u04gekg7/2/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Nice solution

Answer (score 1):

This should be the kind of thing you are looking for:

```js
var myArray = ["Mr", "and", "Sir"];

function checkForString(inputString) {
  var runningTotal = 0;
  //For loop to check each item of the array against the string, to see if it appears
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      runningTotal += inputString.toLowerCase().indexOf(myArray[i].toLowerCase());
  }
  //Check the running total. Each term that DOESN'T appear in the string, returns -1, so multiply by the array length to find the value if none of the items in the array appear in the string
  if (runningTotal == (myArray.length * -1)) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;  
      }
  }
console.log('Mr John Doe = ' + checkForString("Mr John Doe"))
console.log('John Doe = ' + checkForString("John Doe"));
```